# MySql query with subquery very slow

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run this query. It's very slow. After 30sec I still have no results.

- I have indexes on step, source, video_id.
- step 1 is video uploaded
- step 4 is video ready to download
- source 5 is a video type

In encoding_history table, I have many times the same video_id with different steps of process (uploading, encoding, ...)

My need is to get all videos uploaded more than 6 hours ago and still not ready to download.

If I remove the subquery, it's pretty fast.

My table have about 6.000.000 entries.

```
$query = 'SELECT video_id FROM encoding_history WHERE 
video_id NOT IN (SELECT video_id FROM encoding_history WHERE step = 4 AND source = 5 GROUP BY video_id)
AND step = 1
AND source = 5
AND date_added > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR)';
```

Any ideas on how to speed up my results? Thanks.

Comment: Try obtaining query execution plan with [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html). Also use `SQL_NO_CACHE` when debugging.

Comment: Consider using not exists or a join instead of a sub select and get rid of the group by in teh sub select don't think it's needed.

Comment: Can you change subquery to simply be `SELECT DISTINCT video_id FROM encoding_history WHERE step = 4 AND source = 5` (remove the grouping)

Comment: How long does it take to run the sub-query by itself?  Try adding DISTINCT to your sub-query, `SELECT DISTINCT video_id FROM encoding_history WHERE step = 4 AND source = 5 GROUP BY video_id`

Answer (score 1):

Execution plan will help the most as you may be missing indexes that would help but this I think would operate faster.

```
SELECT Eh1.video_id 
FROM encoding_history EH1
LEFT JOIN Encoding_history EH2 
  on EH2.step=4 and EH2.source=5 
  and EH1.step=1 and EH1.source=5
  AND EH1.date_added > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
WHERE Eh2.Video_ID is null
```

Result: 
Return all Video_IDS that are in step 1 with a source of 5 
that do not have a step 4 source 5. 
That were added within the past 6 hours.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that a video is in step 1 and step 4 in the same time so just get rid of the sub query

On another thaught (thanks to  xQbert) you could move this operation to your application instead of the db.

Comment: You're making an assumption that the table doesn't contain historical records as well.  Without knowing the unique key's it may very well have records of videos in step 1 and 4.  Given the attempt showing by the OP, I'm guessing it does in fact have both. but you may also be right, maybe it doesn't have both.  The author could help by providing some sample data to clarify!  (given table name I'm guessing on it having both though)

Comment: Yep, that could be valid indeed

Comment: At the same time no, but the same video_id have different steps.

Comment: in that case you don't need the sub query at all

Comment: @ghousseyn why ? How do you wanna get video_id that are not ready to download if I remove the subquery ?